# Can I prosecute another way if a states attorney declines to?

Tags: maryland, prosecution

Is there any way to prosecute someone and bring them before a judge if the states attorney office declines to? Or can I sue the states attorney and force prosecution?

The state is Maryland if that makes a difference.

Comment: What act(s) or conduct do you intend to prosecute?

Comment: I don't know the answer off the top of my head, but I did manage to do just this right next door in Virginia. I suspect Maryland has a similar provision.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to prosecute someone and bring them before a judge if
> the states attorney office declines to?

No

> Or can I sue the states attorney and force prosecution?

No. You can't bring a private criminal prosecution in Maryland. There are a handful of U.S. states where you can, but Maryland is not one of them.

You can bring a civil lawsuit for money damages and/or injunctive relief against someone who has caused you injury as a private individual.